# Postgresql Truncation vs Deletion When `session_replication_role = replica`

Tags: postgresql

When I first run

```
SET session_replication_role = DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE posts(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

And then run

```
INSERT INTO users(id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO posts(id, user_id) VALUES (1, 1);

SET session_replication_role = replica;

DELETE FROM users;
```

It successfully deletes the row in `users` even though this violates referential integrity because the `session_replication_role = replica`. So far so good.

However, when I instead run

```
INSERT INTO users(id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO posts(id, user_id) VALUES (1, 1);

SET session_replication_role = replica;

TRUNCATE users;
```

I get this output:

```
ERROR:  cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "posts" references "users".
HINT:  Truncate table "posts" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

For performance reasons, I really want to be able to use TRUNCATE and not DELETE. How can I get around this issue without using `TRUNCATE users CASCADE`? I can not use cascading deletes because my DB may have other foreign keys that reference the users table that I do not want to delete.